# How to initialize NSString with UTF-16 string (char16_t)?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, objective-c++, utf-16

I have the following function:

```
long long GetSize() {
    NSString *_filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:m_filePath];
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager]attributesOfItemAtPath:_filePath error:nil] fileSize];
}
```

Specifically, this line `NSString *_filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:m_filePath];`.
Previously `m_filePath` contained an UTF-8 string but now it became contains UTF-16 string `char16_t`, so `initWithUTF8String` became not suitable now.

**Is there a method that accepts the UTF-16 string `char16_t`?**

Comment: see my answer to your other question.. that may help to figure it out for ya. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *_filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:m_filePath length:m_filePathLength];
```

Or you can do this:

```
NSString *_filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%S", m_filePath];
```

If your `m_filePath` is a null-terminated array of 16-bit UTF-16 code units.

Comment: Thank you, but when using the first code this error appeas `Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'const unichar * _Nonnull' (aka 'const unsigned short *') with an rvalue of type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char16_t, std::__1::char_traits<char16_t>, std::__1::allocator<char16_t> >::value_type *' (aka 'const char16_t *')
`, also the second code gives me this warning message `Format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'const std::__1::basic_string<char16_t, std::__1::char_traits<char16_t>, std::__1::allocator<char16_t> >::value_type *' (aka 'const char16_t *')
`.

Comment: @LionKing Try `[[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:(const unichar *)m_filePath length:m_filePathLength];`.

Comment: @RomanPodymov: Unfortunately, another error message: `Cannot cast from type 'az::coString' (aka 'basic_string<char16_t>') to pointer type 'const unichar *' (aka 'const unsigned short *').
`

Comment: @LionKing How the `m_filePath` is declared?

Comment: `m_filePath ` of type `std::u16string` but I use the method `c_str()` to get the `char16_t*`.

Comment: @LionKing Try `[[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:(const unichar *)m_filePath.c_str() length:m_filePathLength];`.

Comment: @RomanPodymov: Finally, it is working, testdrive's code needed `cons unichar *` to work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @LionKing Did you resolve the issue by `[[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:(const unichar *)m_filePath.c_str() length:m_filePathLength];`?

Comment: @RomanPodymov: Yes, it's working. but why do you ask that question, didn't you trust that code?

Comment: @LionKing Just want to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer given by [testdrive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63201386/2229783) I would advise you the following:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:(const unichar *)m_filePath.c_str() length:m_filePathLength]; // m_filePathLength is the number of characters to use from (const unichar *)m_filePath.c_str()
```

So if `m_filePath` is declared as `std::u16string` you should cast it to a `const unichar *`.